# Calculated columns formula today not update (SP 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Created a field with the formula Today + 2 days, checked the next day, the date is old, i.e. in which this column was created, I need the date to be updated every day, how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Today column it needs to be updated. You can do that with either a timer job or by placing a jquery script on a page that is hit by the user. The script could call SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems to do the update. Pass a CAML clause so that you only update the list items where the Today value needs to be updated, e.g. once per day.

Comment: I'm a testing your answer :))

Answer (score 3):

Formulas in calculated columns are only recalculated when the item is saved. The value is static until it is saved again. So the value for [Today] will be the date the last time the item was updated and won't change again until the next time it is updated.

One option might be to write a PoweShell script to read and update every row in the list and run it on the scheduler every day.

Comment: I do not have access to the server, Powershell does not fit uniquely.